# why when i use from mosaic to new raster the created raster has some pixels with 0 value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Why when i use from mosaic to new raster the created raster has some pixels with 0 value? 
I have 2 map that each of them individually has a value (it is volume of run off for pixels) but when i mosaic them some of pixels -as you see in screen shot- have 0 value! i showed 0 values with purple color.

[image]

Comment: What were the precise steps (tools and paremeter values) that you used to see this result?